# Prove that $G=S_n$ iff $K_i\neq K_j$ for all pairs $i,j$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

Suppose $G$ is a group that is transitive on $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, and let $K_i=\{g\in G \;|\; g(k)=k \;\forall k=1,2,\dots,i\}$ for $i=1,2\dots,n$.
Prove that $G=S_n$ iff $K_i\neq K_j$ for all pairs $i,j$ such that $i\neq j$ and $i<n-1$.

$(\implies)$  Assume $i<j$. Take $g=(j\; j+1)$. Clearly $g\in K_i$ but $g\not\in K_j$. Hence $K_i\neq K_j$.

$(\impliedby)$ Note that $$K_n=K_{n-1}<\dots< K_2 < K_1$$
Hence $n \mid |G|\mid n!$. Write $|G|=kn$ where $k$ divides $(n-1)!$.
By Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem, $|K_1|=k$.
I need idea to prove that $k=(n-1)!$

Comment: You better have a faithful action there...

Comment: It's a straightforward induction on $n$. You can assume that $|K_1|=(n-1)!$ by applying induction to $K_1$ acting on the $n-1$ points $\{2,3,\ldots,n\}$.

Comment: Sorry, that is not quite right because you are not told that $G_{1}$ is transitive on $\{2,\ldots,n\}$, but that follows from $K_2 = S_{n-1}$ and $K_1 \ne K_2$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I thought $K_1=S_{n-1}$?

Comment: Yes sorry I meant $K_2 = S_{n-2}$ (on $\{3,\ldots,n\}$. It would be easier to set up the induction if instead of assuming that $G$ is transitive, you assumed that $G= K_0 \ne K_1$, which is actually a slightly weaker assumption.

Comment: @DerekHolt Do you mean that the induction hypothesis is "If $K_n=K_{n-1}<\dots < K_i$, then $K_{i+1}$ is symmetric group"? and we ignore the condition that $G$ is transitive?

Comment: Yes that's the induction hypothesis. You don't exactly ignore your assumption that $G$ is transitive, but you use it to deduce that $G=K_0 \ne K_1$, which allows you to complete the final step of the induction.